# Função dentro de outra

Tags: c#, .net, funções

No JavaScript, consigo estruturar bem meu código colocando funções auxiliares dentro de outras funções. Por exemplo:

Consigo algo semelhante em C#? Se não, como vocês fazem para não deixar as funções auxiliares "soltas" no projeto?

```
function Salva() {
    if(valida()) insereNoBanco();

    function valida() {
        // valida campos
    }

    function insereNoBanco() {
        // insere dados no banco
    }
}
```

Comment: Boa pergunta, porem teve algumas interpretações diferentes, sugiro que leia atentamente as respostas.

Comment: Isto Bruno, leia atentamente as respostas e aceite a que realmente responde bem o que você perguntou. Se ainda não sabe como é a aceitação, veja o [tour].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em JavaScript uma função cria seu próprio escopo, e subfunções herdam escopos.

Em C#, escopos são definidos por blocos (classes ou métodos), e são herdados por classes internas apenas.

Uma expressão similar ao seu exemplo seria a seguinte:

```
internal static class Mae
{
    private static bool PodeSalvar = true;

    internal static void Salva()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Filha.FilhaSalva); //Erro: Fora de escopo

        if (Filha.Valida()) Filha.InsereNoBanco();
    }

    internal static class Filha
    {
        private static bool FilhaSalva = false;

        internal static bool Valida()
        {
            return PodeSalvar; // Funciona, pois Filha herda o escopo de Mae
        }

        internal static void InsereNoBanco()
        {
            // insere dados no banco
        }
    }
}
```

Note que `PodeSalvar` está definida na classe `Mae`, e o método `Valida()` da classe interna `Filha` tem acesso a ela, mesmo que tenha sido definida como `Private`.

Entretanto, `FilhaSalva` não pode ser lida por métodos na classe `Mae`, mesmo com um descritor completo (`Filha.FilhaSalva`) - já que `FilhaSalva` é definida como `Private`.

Comment: +1 porque está correto e não deixa de ser uma alternativa em algum caso específico. É uma uma solução complexa demais para os casos comuns e acho que até você concorda.

Comment: @bigown para dizer a verdade, sim, concordo - porém subclasse é o único caso de escopo de acesso que me ocorreu que não tinha ainda sido discutido.

Comment: Embora os termos aí estão confusos. Já não tinha gostado os nomes das classes porque leva crer que isto é uma herança, o que qualquer que conheça a linguagem vê que não é. Tudo bem. Agora você falou em subclasse, Remete novamente à herança, o que não é. Isto é uma *inner class* (classe interna?). Isto não muda a resposta, só para ficar mais claro.

Comment: @bigown você está certo, o termo correto é classe interna. Obrigado pela dica, já ajustei a resposta.

Comment: Ele gostou da sua solução complexa :D Não parece ser o que ele quer de fato mas cada um com a sua cabeça

Comment: É a resposta certa porque aborda de maneira concisa o escopo de funções em C#.

Answer (score 8):

Em C# isto não era possível ([tem no C# 7](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/259), ver mais em [outra pergunta qui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130191/101)). Daria pra criar *delegates*, mas duvido que seja o que deseja.

Pra falar a verdade vejo pouca utilidade pra isto. Normalmente isto só será necessário se o código estiver muito grande e ainda assim, a solução não é criar *inner functions*, como mostrado no JavaScript. Isto é feito no JS porque é uma linguagem que tem limitações para limitar visibilidade e escopo.

A ideia de estruturar partes do código em funções separadas é boa, separa as responsabilidades, mas não precisa ser dentro de outra. Crie outras funções fora dela. A única desvantagem disto é que externamente qualquer outro método da classe poderá chamá-la. Se fosse interna, só ela poderia chamar a função. Mas isto não costuma ser problema.

Evidentemente deve criar este função/método, como `private` para ela não poder ser acessada fora da classe.

```
public void Salva() => if (valida()) insereNoBanco();
private bool valida() {
    // valida campos
}
private void insereNoBanco() {
    // insere dados no banco
}
```

Eu não faria isto mas a resposta do Daniel colocou um exemplo do que eu falei inicialmente na resposta sobre *lambda* e que é o que mais se aproxima da simulação de *inner fucntion* usada no JavaScript:

```
public void Salva() {
    Func<bool> valida = () => {
        // valida campos
    };

    Action insereNoBanco = () => {
        // insere dados no banco
    };
    if (valida()) insereNoBanco();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/InnerFunction.cs).

É desnecessário fazer isto, pode ter efeitos indesejados e não é idiomático em C#.

Comment: No que eu entendi da pergunta dele, ele não que os métodos auxiliares fiquem na mesma classe "arquivo"

Comment: Em nenhum momento ele mostra isto. Parece que você presumiu isto. E na sua resposta parece que você presumiu que todo mundo entende o que você está dizendo, o que é para fazer. Do jeito que eu entendi, não dá para fazer o que você sugere em todas situações. Se estas funções acessam membros privados da instância da classe, não pode ser `static`, muito menos, de outra classe. E tem boa chance disto ocorrer, afinal no exemplo dele, a função auxiliar era muito interna e os nomes indicam que fará algo que depende de outros valores existentes.

Comment: **Se não, como vocês fazem para não deixar as funções auxiliares "soltas" no projeto?** `Soltas` pra mim significa que as funçoes são `auxiliares` não fazem parte do escopo de uma classe, ou seja, podem ser usadas em muitos locais e que ele não quer implementar novamente os metodos em todas classes, ele não quer deixar `perdido` seus metodos

Comment: Mas aí se pode ser usada em qualquer parte do projeto, não é o que ele fez no exemplo dele. Ele não quer solta de tudo, é solta da função que vai usar. Tem que ler o contexto. Não pode ler só a frase da pergunta. No exemplo a função é interna justamente pra não usar em outras partes do projeto. Provavelmente você não entenda o conceito de *inner fucntion*. Assim como você tinha postado um exemplo que não simulava herança múltipla, fazia outra coisa, agora, você está fazendo outra coisa, e não simulando uma *inner fucntion*.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode declarar funções dentro de um método usando as expressões lambda:

```
Func<int, string> convertIntParaString = (num1) => num1.ToString();

Action<string, int> doisParamsSemRetorno = (str1, num1) =>
{
    str1.ToUpper();
    num1.ToString();
};
```

Usando o seu código como exemplo:

```
void Salva() 
{
    Func<bool> valida = () => 
    {
        // valida campos
        return true;
    };

    Action insereNoBanco = () =>
    {
        // insere dados no banco
    };

    if(valida())
        insereNoBanco();
}
```

Comment: Resposta criativa, foi até copiada por outra resposta ;-)

Answer (score 1):

O Ideal seria você criar uma classe de apoio contendo os métodos que você precisa. Assim o seu código fica mais organizado e fácil manutenção. Abaixo um exemplo bem simples.

```
namespace Exemple
{
    public class Suporte
    {
        public static void Mensagem()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Este é um método de apoio");
        }
    }
}

namespace Exemple
{
    public class Principal
    {
        public void ExibeMensagem()
        {
           Suporte.Mensagem();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Genericamente falando não tem necessidade alguma criar uma classe auxiliar. Pode ter em alguma situação específica. Mas pra funções que estariam dentro da função, seria um exagero criar uma classe auxiliar. De qualquer forma, se fosse um caso em que isto é interessante, não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: @bigown parece que voce e o unico com opinião diferente.

Comment: Esta resposta está caindo no mesmo erro, ela faz outra coisa diferente do que está na pergunta. Tanto que, apenas para ilustrar, o exemplo dela e da outra resposta errada mostram operações totalmente diferentes do exemplo da pergunta. A minha resposta mostra como resolver o problema do AP e a resposta do Daniel mostra como simular o mesmo recurso de forma próxima ao do JS mas não idiomática em C#. Esta resposta também impede o acesso de membros privados da instância da classe em questão.