# Como declarar uma função dentro de outra função em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, funções, característica-linguagem

Em Delphi é possível declarar função dentro do bloco de uma determinada função, veja este exemplo feito em Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.btnRunClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mostrarNome('Carvalho');
end;

function TForm1.mostrarNome(nome: String): String;
  function transformaMaiuscula(str: String): String;
  begin
    Result := UpperCase(str);    
  end;
begin
  ShowMessage(transformaMaiuscula(nome));
end;
```

A saída será:

> CARVALHO //Em letras maiúsculas

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer o mesmo em C#, declarar uma função dentro de outra função. Veja este código em C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mostraNome("Carvalho");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void mostraNome(string nome) 
    {
        static string transformaMaiuscula(string str)
        {
            return str.ToUpper();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(transformaMaiuscula());
    }
}
```

O código em C# acima não funciona, o compilador diz que a sintaxe é inválida, porem, ele serve apenas como ilustração.

Existe um meio de fazer isto em C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Gambiarra

Até o C# 6 a única forma era o uso de [*lambda*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) que nada mais é que um ponteiro para função (eventualmente pode armazenar variáveis capturadas também), assim é possível escrever o corpo de uma função e armazenar em uma variável ou passar como argumento, ou ainda retornar na função que foi declarada.

```
Func<string string> transformaMaiuscula = (string str) => str.ToUpper();
transformaMaiuscula("Teste"); //obviamente pode fazer o que quiser
```

Esse recurso é um açúcar sintático em cima de [`delegates`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101238/101).

Ele existe desde o C# 3. No C# 2 existia a sintaxe do `delegate` que é parecido com a sintaxe da *lambda*, porém menos conveniente. Em C# 1 existia o `delegate`, mas a sintaxe era tão inconveniente que tinha que declarar o delegado e depois declarar e definir um método separado, ou seja, nem podia declarar dentro de outro método.

```
Func<string string> transformaMaiuscula = delegate(string str) {
    return str.ToUpper();
};
Console.WriteLine(transformaMaiuscula(nome));
```

Esse [`Func<string string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) é um delegado já declarado pelo .NET, para sua conveniência. Em outras circunstâncias também [poderia usar um `Action` e muito eventualmente um `Predicate`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90058/101). Só o `Predicate` existia no C# 2, o que era bem limitante, e que obrigava na prática declarar o delegado fora do método.

Não vou nem usar o exemplo do C# porque sequer parece com o que está sendo pedido, mas a declaração do delegado seria `delegate string transformaMaiuscula(string str)`, depois é declarar o método com a mesma assinatura. A declaração vai dentro de um tipo, mas não dentro de um método.

Note que usar um delegado com [sintaxe de *lambda* é bem diferente de usar um método normal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116095/101). Até pode simular essa ideia, mas elas possuem características diferentes. E é uma tremenda gambiarra fazer isso. Inclusive tem consumo de memória, gasto de processamento e possível perda da confiabilidade em casos mais complexos se o programador não tomar certos cuidados.

Se você precisa de um delegado aí tudo bem, pague o preço de usá-lo. Não é o caso da pergunta.

#### Sintaxe *lambda* fora do método

C# 6 permitiu inclusive que a sintaxe de *lambdas* fosse usada em qualquer método, assim quando o método é muito simples dá para declarar seu corpo de forma mais simples. Ele passou ter a sintaxe da *lamba*, mas não sua semântica. Só foi possível usar em métodos normais dos tipos.

```
string transformaMaiuscula(string str) => str.ToUpper();
```

Não que isto ajude a pergunta, coloquei como curiosidade porque as pessoas demoram para se acostumar com recursos novos.

## Solução correta

Ai pode-se pensar: vai se fazer o que se não tem outra coisa? Pois bem, eu não usaria uma *lambda* quando só se deseja um função local (aninhada), como mostra a pergunta. Minha solução, e esta é a recomendação oficial, é simplesmente desaninhar a função. Apenas crie um método separado, provavelmente privado e estático e chame-o onde precisa.

Ele só tem um inconveniente, outros métodos da classe poderão chamá-lo. Mas é algo administrável e não gera nenhum outro custo.

```
private static string transformaMaiuscula(string str) => str.ToUpper();
```

Aí dentro do seu método simplesmente chama o método `transformaMaiuscula()` como outro qualquer.

## C# 7

No C# 7 já é possível usar a sintaxe de função local, assim não paga preço algum e não corre risco, nem mesmo de permitir a chamada desta função por outros membros da classe.

A sintaxe é quase a usada pelo AP:

```
static void mostraNome(string nome) {
    static string transformaMaiuscula(string str) {
        return str.ToUpper();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(transformaMaiuscula(nome));
}
```

O `static` foi permitido na sintaxe, ele dá mais segurança para evitar capturas indevidas de variáveis no contexto maior.

Note que você pode declarar o método local depois de usá-lo. Não é possível fazer isto com *lambda*, a declaração deve vir antes sempre.

De forma simplificada poderia usar assim:

```
static void mostraNome(string nome) {
    static string transformaMaiuscula(string str) => str.ToUpper();
    Console.WriteLine(transformaMaiuscula(nome));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/LocalFunction.cs).

Answer (score 7):

Diretamente, não. Mas você pode declarar uma [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) ou [`delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx), ou ainda [`Func<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx), que é quase a mesma coisa.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    delegate void Teste2();

    public static void Main()
    {
        Action Teste = () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Teste!");
        };

        Teste2 teste2 = delegate() {
            Console.WriteLine("Teste 2!");
        };

        Func<string, string> teste3 = delegate(string argumento) {
            return argumento + " " + argumento;
        };

        Teste();
        teste2();
        Console.WriteLine(teste3("Buemba!"));
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

[Fiz um Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cq5mfM).

Resultado:

```
Teste!
Teste 2!
Buemba! Buemba!
Hello World
```

A diferença entre eles é que `delegate` precisa ser fortemente tipado. `Action` é um pouco mais dinâmico, mas não retorna valor algum. Para retornar valores, use `Func<TArgumentos, TRetorno>`, onde `TRetorno` é o que será retornado e `TArgumentos` são os tipos dos argumentos.

Comment: É possível eu especificar um parâmetro e um retorna para a Action?

Comment: Sim, vou editar com mais um exemplo.

Comment: Acho que agora tem tudo.

Comment: Sim, mas vou fazer outra pergunta a respeito do `Func<>`.

Comment: Ok, fique à vontade :)

Comment: Só para conhecimento, já tem uma proposta aprovada para o C# 7 que trabalha justamente com a ideia que a pergunta tinha, ela se chama "Nested local function". https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/259