# É possível forçar que um método só seja chamado por um outro em específico?

Tags: c#, método, scope

Eu tenho um método pai que chama um método filho, eu gostaria que o método filho só pudesse ser chamado exclusivamente pelo método pai, seria possível?

Exemplo:

```
public void MetodoPai(){
    //codigo
    MetodoFilho();
    //codigo
} 

void MetodoFilho(){
    //codigo
} 


public void OutroMetodoQualquer(){
    //codigo
    MetodoFilho(); //Causar erro na compilação ou algo do tipo
}
```

Comment: isso está tudo misturado na mesma classe ?

Comment: Sim, está tudo dentro de uma classe só

Comment: Não. Talvez a solução para o problema que você esteja enfrentando seja outra. Poderemos tentar ajudar através de um contexto e um [mcve]

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza você quer um exemplo mais verificável que esse?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti o que você precisa são [`local functions`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions), funções declaradas de um método que só estão disponíveis dentro do escopo desse método.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Me explica quais pontos do meu exemplo está em desacordo com o exemplo M.C.V.

Comment: Você está partindo do que acredita ser uma solução. Minha proposta foi que você mudasse a perspectiva da pergunta, partindo do problema.

Comment: Não existe problema no meu código, é uma pergunta se existe ou não um recurso, não existe solução para algo que não tem um problema, tem uma duvida.

Comment: o que Diego quis dizer, é para você explicar qual a necessidade do "método filho só pudesse ser chamado exclusivamente pelo método pai" pois para essa necessidade podem haver outras soluções...

Comment: @RovannLinhalis agora sim entendi, eu quero delimitar não permitir esse método ser chamado por outros como uma forma de organização e prevenção que outro programador(ou até eu) use o método futuramente pois ele só existe em função do método pai.

Comment: Talvez seja algo bem inútil, mas eu acredito que assim o código fica mais organizado, posso estar tremendamente errado também.

Comment: certo, acho que o mais adequado seria organizar isso em classes... OU se você tem que usar a função mais de uma vez dentro do método pai... pode usar a função função que o maniero colocou na resposta, E se só vai usar isso uma vez, não vejo nem o porque estaria dentro de outra função...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se tudo estiver dentro da mesma classe (só com os comentários que isso ficou claro) a [função local é a solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181290/101). Obviamente que está limitado a um método, não tem como fazer um método ser acessado por uma lista de métodos.

Tudo tem que ser dentro do escopo ou especificado o escopo de forma geral, não específica, a não ser que faça uma ferramenta externa que seja obrigado passar em todo compilação. Um do motivos da criação do [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) é justamente fazer esse tipo de ferramenta. Mas é claro que se não passar por ela não vai proibir nada.

Lembrando que obrigar ou proibir algo sempre ocorre quando o programador quer seguir os protocolos padrões, se ele quiser passar por cima ele sempre consegue. Isto seria uma proteção contra um erro inadvertido, não segurança contra fraudes.

Se a função local não atende, o máximo que o compilador padrão permite é proibir sua chamada fora da classe (`private`), ou fora da hierarquia da classe (`protected`) ou fora do *assembly* (`internal`) ou uma combinação dos dois últimos, ou pode limitar mais ainda e permitir que um método da classe seja o único a acessar uma [função função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130191/101). Mas não dá para dizer nominalmente quem pode acessar.

É possível dizer que [pode ser acessado por algum outro *assembly* específico com um atributo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Answer (score -1):

Talvez a melhor forma de solução seja separar por classes, onde o método Pai e o método Filho estejam na mesma classe, porém o filho é privado e só pode ser acessado de dentro da própria classe. E uma segunda classe que implementa a primeira. A segunda classe só visualizará o método Pai, porque ele é público. O método Filho estará oculto para esta segunda classe.

O que "Leonardo Bonetti" quis dizer com problemas é que Programas são construídos para resolverem um problema. Isto é, você precisa somar dois números, isso é o problema: "somar dois números". Então você cria soluções para resolver este problema. Sabendo o que você precisa resolver, facilita para a gente indicar uma solução.

De qualquer forma, classe é a melhor forma para resolver essa questão de ocultar métodos, porém a resolução certa só é possível sabendo o escopo do seu problema.