# Por que usar funções locais?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem

Recentemente foi introduzido no [C# 7.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) as funções locais, onde você permite criar funções ou métodos sem assinatura dentro de outros métodos/funções de forma aninhada.

```
int MinhaFormula(int x, int y) {
    int y = x + calculoInterno(x, y);
    return y - x;

    int calculoInterno(int a, int b) {
        return b + a - (3 * b);
    }
}
```

Por que usar funções aninhadas às outras? Não entendi a utilidade do uso de funções onde estarão visíveis somente à uma função. Por que a Microsoft fez isso?

Comment: Uma dessas ou o conjunto delas responde a pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181290/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/293979/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130191/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142150/101 .

Comment: @Maniero não. Responde com o que é útil usar as funções locais, mas ainda não me estabelecem um porquê usá-las. Ao que vi nos exemplos, estas funções são gerais e não são objetivas à função onde está declarada, enxergando então a possibilidade de aninhar essas funções locais à um escopo maior do que abranger somente uma função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citando a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions):

> Funções locais tornam a intenção do seu código clara. Qualquer pessoa que ler seu código poderá ver que o método não pode ser chamado, exceto pelo método que o contém. Para projetos de equipe, elas também impossibilitam que outro desenvolvedor chame o método por engano diretamente de qualquer outro lugar na classe ou no struct.

Ou seja, funções locais forma adicionadas com o intuito de deixar claro a qual escopo está atrelado, além de impedir que desenvolvedores distraídos chamem essa função em outra parte da classe que não deveria ter acesso. Isso é útil quando uma função precisa de vários trechos repetidos de código, mas que devem se referir exclusivamente aquele escopo.

Imaginemos o seguinte contexto: existe um método que terá que repetir diversas vezes um cálculo específico, para não ter replicação de código, eu posso encapsular esse cálculo em uma função local, que só poderá ser executada por esse método. De forma bastante simplificada, podemos utilizar o exemplo a seguir para isso:

```
public class Exemplo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SomaDeSomatarias(100,200,300));
    }

    private static int SomaDeSomatarias(int numero1, int numero2, int numero3)
    {
         var soma1 = Somatoria(numero1);
         var soma2 = Somatoria(numero2);
         var soma3 = Somatoria(numero3);

         return soma1 + soma2 + soma3;
         int Somatoria(int num)
         {
             var soma = 0;
             for(var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
                 soma += i;
             }
             return soma;
         }
    } 
}
```

Claro que isso é só uma exemplificação simples, mas isso pode ser utilizado com diversas finalidades como, por exemplo, tratamento de nomes de arquivos, cuja a regra é relativa, exclusivamente, para um determinado contexto.